# Compiling a portable high level language package for wrapping a c/c++ lib

Tags: c++, c, cmake, portability

I am working on a package for a high level language (Matlab) that wraps the functions provided by a third party c/c++ lib.

## Goal

Pre-compile the package such that it can be run on any computer without installing the external lib's non-standard dependencies.

## Set up

The external lib is a git submodule that is built with cmake. I have an internal library that provides functions for converting between the external lib's data types and Matlab's data types. Then there are individual c functions (refered to as mex functions) dependent on the internal and external library that can be called directly in Matlab after being compiled. Ideally the internal library is compiled as a shared library so the mex files don't all have their own copy of common functions.

## Attempts

1. The easiest thing to do is build the external library as a shared library then have both the internal library and the mex functions link against the external library but then there are runtime dependencies on non-standard libraries.
2. Build the external library as a static library and have the internal library linked against it then have the mex functions linked against only the internal library. By default, the internal library will only contain the symbols from the external libraries it depends on, so any other symbols needed by the mex functions will be missing. GCC has a linker option `--whole-archive` which forces the linker to add all objects from the static external library into the internal library. I've been setting it with

```
target_link_libraries(internallib
  PRIVATE -Wl,--whole-archive externallib -Wl,--no-whole-archive
)
```

From my understanding, having the external lib between `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive` ensures that the linker will only link all the objects for that library and not all the libraries. This compiles fine but when testing, there are undefined symbol errors at runtime for symbols defined in the external library and I'm not sure why.

3. Instead of linking against the external library, add the external libraries object files as sources for the internal library:

```
add_library(internallib
  SHARED
  ${src_files}
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:externallib>
)
```

I'm still getting the same symbol not found errors and I don't think this will prevent the runtime dependencies on the external libraries dependencies anyway.

4. Link both the internal library and mex functions against the static external library. This seems to work (on both Linux and macOS) but fails on Windows (using gcc/g++ from mingw) with multiple definition errors. I believe this is due to the internal shared library picking up symbols from the external lib that the mex functions also need, so they're defined in both the internal and external library and the linker doesn't know which to use for the mex functions.

I think option 2 is the most promising, I just can't get it to add all the symbols from the external library. Am I misusing/misunderstanding `--whole-archive`?

Comment: IMHO, you can't achieve portability because libraries are a compiler specific entity, especially with C++. C++ has function overloading, which plays havoc with linkers and many mangle the names.  There is no standard for name mangling.  There is no required standard for libraries.

Comment: The code and libraries will be OS dependent.  Windows is not like Linux.  The APIs are different to say the least.  You'll need libraries built on the target operating systems.

Comment: Be aware that different platforms may have different processors.  Each brand of processor has a different assembly language.  For example, the Linux OS can be run on ARM processors or Intel processors.

Comment: The package gets compiled on each OS it supports. The issue is not that a package compiled on one OS isn't running on another.

Comment: I don't think it's an ideal solution, but a workaround is making the internal library an object library instead so the mex function are compiled with all the library's object files and then both the internal "library" and the mex functions are linked against the external library at the same time. Builds are succeding and tests are running fine. `readelf` reports no third party libraries needed.

Comment: You have a limited notion of portability, which you didn't state in your question.   `readelf` is specific to systems that have an ELF executable file format - which includes some (not all) unix variants, including linux but not all BSD flavours.   Other systems have a different executable format.   Would have been better to state that constraint as part of your definition of portability (since the approach you're taking will not be portable to a fair number of other systems, including windows).